# c# update database but not update the database

Tags: sql-server-ce

ive been trying to update my database. somehow, there is no error for my coding but the data does not updated the value in the database.  below were my code

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = Program Files\\PROGRAM\\DATABSE.sdf");
conn.Open();

SqlCeCommand command1 = new SqlCeCommand("Update LOT_ATT SET UPI ='" + txtUPI.Text + "' WHERE HEX_ID = (Select UPI from LOT_ATT Where ID ='" + txtUPI.Text + "'", conn);
SqlCeCommand command2 = new SqlCeCommand("Update LOT_ATT SET NEGERI='" + txtNegeri.Text + "'WHERE HEX_ID = (Select NEGERI from LOT_ATT Where ID ='" + txtUPI.Text + "'", conn);
SqlCeCommand command3 = new SqlCeCommand("Update LOT_ATT SET DAERAH='" + txtDaerah.Text + "'WHERE HEX_ID = (Select DAERAH from LOT_ATT Where ID ='" + txtUPI.Text + "'", conn);
SqlCeCommand command4 = new SqlCeCommand("Update LOT_ATT SET MUKIM ='" + txtMukim.Text + "'WHERE HEX_ID = (Select MUKIM from LOT_ATT Where ID ='" + txtUPI.Text + "'", conn);
SqlCeCommand command5 = new SqlCeCommand("Update LOT_ATT SET LOT ='" + txtLot.Text + "'WHERE HEX_ID= (Select LOT from LOT_ATT Where ID ='" + txtUPI.Text + "'", conn);
SqlCeCommand command6 = new SqlCeCommand("Update LOT_ATT SET AREA='" + txtArea.Text + "'WHERE HEX_ID = (Select AREA from LOT_ATT Where ID ='" + txtUPI.Text + "'", conn);

conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Updated!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute your commands. Just defining them does not execute them.

```
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
// etc, etc.
```

Make sure to do this before you close your connection.